# Redirection using servlet not working

Tags: javascript, servlets

I was trying to redirect after an alert message in servlet something like this :

```
out.println("<script>alert('Group Request Invitation Canceled');document.location='individualdetailstoadd.jsp?personid=''"+idperson+"'</script>");
```

But its not working.Though if I remove the redirection,the alert message is displayed .
What can be the reason ?Please help

Comment: It sounds more like a Javascript error to me than a servlet error. The servlet is obviously rendering the code correctly. Can you debug your webpage using a Javascript debugger e.g. the Chrome console?

Comment: @DavidBrossard I think am missing some quotes closing.Am i right?

Comment: @DavidBrossard I think error is in part document.location='individualdetailstoadd.jsp?personid=''"+idperson+"'</script>"

Comment: You probably have a path problem... verify the full address before and after, there is something missing I suppose.

Comment: @AlexandreLavoie No the page openes fine when i open it .I think am missing some quotes .

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/503093/how-can-i-make-a-redirect-page-in-jquery-javascript

Comment: @DavidBrossard Hey,I want it using servlet,as i have very less html code,so i make a servlet for it

Comment: Did you consider using the servlet response's sendRedirect() method?

Comment: @DavidBrossard This method will directly redirect the page without displaying alert msg

Comment: Yes, true... I would suggest you write a basic minimal HTML page that does the trick and once you have that working, move the code to a servlet response.

Comment: @DavidBrossard Could you please check which quotes am missing ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54541/discussion-between-david-brossard-and-user3522121).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need the single quotes before the double quotes.

Try

```
out.println("<script>alert('Group Request Invitation Canceled');document.location='individualdetailstoadd.jsp?personid="+idperson+"'</script>");
```

The generated HTML will be along the following lines:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<body>
<script>
alert('Group Request Invitation Canceled');
document.location='individualdetailstoadd.jsp?personid=5'</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I tested this in my browser and it redirects successfully.